# How to convert this geometry location format to a qgis usable format?

Tags: qgis, well-known-text

I am a beginner with regard to dealing with gis information, so please bear with me. I would be obliged if someone could help. I have data on asssembly constituencies of Delhi, with these constituencies being represented as polygons. But I am unfamiliar with the format in which it's geometry is given. Can someone tell me how to convert this to a format which can help me use the data on qgis or google fusion table.[image: How to convert geometry in this format into maybe WKT format or nay which can be used on qgis]

Comment: Without any further details, it is hardly possible to give you any hints. Is the data available online? Can you add a screenshot with the folder content?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are reading it off a KML file. If you have the original KML for this, then you can open it in QGIS

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to shapefile using delimited text layer plugin in qgis. Change the geometry fields to POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3))format and then convert .csv to .shp format.